# How do I change PHP error output design?

Tags: php, error-handling

Very stupid question but how do I display PHP error in a table design?

Here are images:
https://www.google.co.jp/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enJP757JP757&biw=1378&bih=752&tbm=isch&source=hp&q=php+error+orange&oq=php+error&gs_l=img

My error message looks like boring plain text. Cannot find a way by google search...

I use MAMP4.2 and PHP7.1.6 on my machine.

Comment: Install [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can install xdebug for good look php error. lol

Comment: Xdebug it is. Thank you!